# Passing back JSON and input files to a controller MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass my JSON object and two input file fields back to my MVC 4 controller from my view. If I set `async: true,` in my ajax I get the JSON object and no files. If I set my `async: false,` I get the files and no JSON.

Any ideas as to why I can't send everything back to my controller? I'm trying to upload images to my server.

Also as a side note, my JSON never returns success, it always errors, but the value is still passed to the controller when `async: true,`.

Any help would be great, thank you!

JSON:

```
var json = {Details:{"Name":"Person Name","Url":"http://stackoverflow.com/"};
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
 url: '/Admin/Create',
 type: 'POST',
 data: JSON.stringify(json),
 dataType: 'json',
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 async: false,
 cache: false,
 success: function () {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
  },
 complete: function () {
    console.log('COMPLETE');
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Create(AdminObjectModel jsonData,
IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> small_images)
{
 ...
 return Redirect("/admin/create");
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/Admin/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
...
  <input type="file" id="images" class="span6" name="images" multiple />
...
  <input type="file" id="small-images" class="span6" name="small_images" />
...
</form>
```

Comment: it's always returning error and not success because you are telling the ajax call to expect to get json data back by saying `dataType: 'json',`. It hits the error handler since you are doing a redirect and not passing back JSON

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a solution, not sure if it's the best one, but it works.

View > AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Admin/CreateJSON',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function () {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log('COMPLETE');
    }
});
```

View > HTML:

```
<form action="/Admin/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  ...
  <input type="file" id="images" class="span6" name="images" multiple />
  ...
  <input type="file" id="small-images" class="span6" name="small_images" />
  ...
</form>
```

Controller:

```
private static AdminObjectModel create = new RecipeObjectModel();

[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public void CreateJSON(AdminObjectModel jsonData)
{
    create = jsonData;
}

[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> small_images)
{
    string t = create.Details.Name;
    ...
    return Redirect("/admin/create");
}
```